# How to get input fields seperated with space?

Tags: html, button, textbox, bootstrap-4

I couldn't get the text box and button separated by space but in one line, can someone explain to me what span actually does?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#custom-collapse"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button><a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">GLOW</a>

        <div class="col-sm-5 pull-right hidden-md hidden-print hidden-sm hii" style="padding-top:10px">
            <form action="login.asp" method="post" name="Form1">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txtLogin" name="txtLogin" placeholder="Login" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your login ID." required="required"/><span class="input-group-btn">
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" id="txtPass" name="txtPass" placeholder="Password" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address." required="required"/>
                    <button class="btn btn-g btn-round" id="btnlogin" type="submit">Login</button></span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

If I put `&nbsp;` between the two text fields I end up like this:
[image]

Added my CSS code

```
.container { width:1170px }

.container-fluid > .navbar-collapse,
.container-fluid > .navbar-header,
.container > .navbar-collapse,
.container > .navbar-header { 
    margin-right:0;
    margin-left:0
}

.col-sm-5 { width:41.66666667% }

.input-group {
    position:relative;
    display:table;
    border-collapse:separate
}

.form-control {
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 33px;
    border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
    border-radius: 2px;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.input-group-btn{
    position:relative;
    font-size:0;
    white-space:nowrap
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your markup in order to solve this with Bootstrap. Namely:

- Remove the `<span>` after the login field (ant the closing `</span>` after the button), as it is not in the right place, and also the `.input-group-btn` class is not the one you want to use here.
- Wrap just the button into `<div class="input-group-append">`.
- Remove the custom styles from `.input-group` and `.input-group-btn`, and `height: 33px;` from `.form-control`. Generally it is not a good idea to overwrite the default classes.
- Finally, you can add the space needed between the two inputs by applying `margin-right` on `#txtLogin`. You can do this with custom css styles, or by using one of the `.mr-{}` [Spacing utility](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) classes, e.g. `.mr-2`.

You will find the documentation of the features used here under the [Multiple inputs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#multiple-inputs) and the [Button addons](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#button-addons) sections of the Bootstrap 4 documentation.

```css
.container { width:1170px }

.container-fluid>.navbar-collapse,.container-fluid>
.navbar-header,.container>
.navbar-collapse,.container>.navbar-header { 
    margin-right:0;
    margin-left:0
}

.col-sm-5 { width:41.66666667% }

/*.input-group {
    position:relative;
    display:table;
    border-collapse:separate
}*/

.form-control {
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 11px;
    /*height: 33px;*/
    border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
    /*border-radius: 2px;*/
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}

/*.input-group-btn{
    position:relative;
    font-size:0;
    white-space:nowrap
}*/
```

```html
<form action="login.asp" method="post" name="Form1">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control mr-2" type="text" id="txtLogin" name="txtLogin" placeholder="Login" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your login ID." required="required"/>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" id="txtPass" name="txtPass" placeholder="Password" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address." required="required"/>
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-g btn-round" id="btnlogin" type="submit">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `&nbsp;` before the button to add a space. Is that what you are attempting to do?

EDIT: I don't know what you btn btn-g or btn-round css classes are but if you add a margin value inline(as in in the buttons style tag) it will overwrite whatever is in your css classed and give you the space

```css
.container{width:1170px}

.container-fluid>.navbar-collapse,.container-fluid>
.navbar-header,.container>
.navbar-collapse,.container>.navbar-header { 
  margin-right:0;
  margin-left:0
}

.col-sm-5{width:41.66666667%}

.input-group {
position:relative;
display:table;
border-collapse:separate
}

.form-control {
font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 2px;
font-size: 11px;
height: 33px;
border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
border-radius: 2px;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.input-group-btn{
 position:relative;
 font-size:0;
 white-space:nowrap
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#custom-collapse"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button><a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">GLOW</a>

            <!--<div class="col-sm-5 pull-right hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-print hidden-sm hii" style="padding-top:10px">-->
            <div class="col-sm-5 pull-right hidden-md hidden-print hidden-sm hii" style="padding-top:10px">
                <form action="login.asp" method="post" name="Form1">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txtLogin" name="txtLogin" placeholder="Login" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your login ID." required="required"/><span class="input-group-btn">
                        <input class="form-control" type="password" id="txtPass" name="txtPass" placeholder="Password" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address." required="required"/>
                    <button class="btn btn-g btn-round" id="btnlogin" type="submit" style="margin-left:10px">Login</button></span>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>

      </div>
```

Comment: Can you add your CSS to your question?

Comment: added CSS to my questions

Comment: I don't know what you btn btn-g or btn-round css classes are but if you add a margin value inline(as in in the buttons style tag) it will overwrite whatever is in your css classed and give you the space.